# modx plugin 404 and show something that not exits in the database

Tags: php, plugins, modx, modx-revolution

I need to show some data in modx 404 event.

I have some files in a directory. When i got a specific url in 404 event i wanted to show a file from a specific directory which is not a modx resource.

I was not able to show any custom output.
how can i do that?

in plugin i have set plugin event to onPageNotFind and i have tried like this:

```
global $modx;
if ($modx->event->name == 'OnPageNotFound') {
   $out = file_get_contents('my_file');
   $modx->event->output( $out);
}
```

i also tried like this:

```
global $modx;
if ($modx->event->name == 'OnPageNotFound') {
   $out = file_get_contents('my_file');
   $strContent = &$modx->resource->_output;
   $strContent = $out;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: You're using `$modx->event->output( $out);` (output), then `_output` in your second one.

Comment: this is not the big deal @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1):

If you are only firing your plugin on `OnPageNotFound` there is no need to add the check for the event name. That's only necessary if your plugin handles multiple events with different code.

You also cannot use `$modx->resource->output` because this plugin fires when MODX has not found a resource.

Your plugin could be as simple as this:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/404.html';
$modx->sendRedirect($url);
```

That will just redirect the user to your static file when MODX cannot find a match for the requested url.

More on `modX::sendRedirect()`: http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/class-reference/modx/modx.sendredirect

Comment: I do not have resources for cached files. So i can not redirect to any url. I have found another way to do it.I will post the answer here. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but note that the accepted answer here should be the one that correctly answers your question - not what eventually fixed your problem. My answer shows exactly how to 'show a file from a specific directory which is not a modx resource.'

Comment: With 'show a file from a specific directory which is not a modx resource' i also mention that we do not have resource to show this file. you have redirected it into a resource. I do not wanted to do this.

Comment: No, it's been redirected to the static file - not a MODX resource.